# Name columns when importing csv to dataframe in dask

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dask

I would like to name columns when I import a csv to a dataframe with dask in Python.The code I use looks like this:

> ```
> for i  in range(1, files + 1):
>     filename = str(i) + 'GlobalActorsHeatMap.csv'
>     runs[i] = dd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
> ```

I would like to use an array with names for each column:

> names = ['tribute', 
>                  'percent_countries_active',
>                  'num_wars',
>                  'num_tributes',
>                  'war', 
>                  'war_to_tribute_ratio',
>                  'US_wealth',
>                  'UK_wealth',
>                  'NZ_wealth'
>                 ]

Is this possible to do directly?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `names` argument for the `read_csv`

```
names = [...]
dd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=names)
```

Read more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thanks. The error was that the number of columns in names didn't match the number of elements in the csv.